# Is there an alternative to using comments for users who don't have enough Rep to chat, as it is frowned upon to chat in comments?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, chat, privileges

I often get the warning `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?` but a lot of the time, I am helping new users. What should I do to avoid discussion - should I suggest an external chat site, or continue using the comments?